# List Inactive Directories

Tags: powershell

I'm a big dumb dummy trying to create a PowerShell script which will list all directories that contain files and subdirectories that have not been modified in 90 days. I'm not an experienced scripter, so I searched around and found the script below.

```vb
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objStartFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Scripts")
Set colFiles = objStartFolder.Files

i = 0

For Each objFile in colFiles
    dtmDate = objFile.DateLastModified
    intAge = DateDiff("d", dtmDate, Date)

    If intAge < 90 Then
        i = 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If i = 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo objStartFolder.Path
End If

ShowSubfolders(objStartFolder) 

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each objSubfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objSubFolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

        i = 0

        For Each objFile in colFiles
            dtmDate = objFile.DateLastModified
            intAge = DateDiff("d", dtmDate, Date)

            If intAge < 90 Then
                i = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If i = 0 Then
            Wscript.Echo objSubfolder.Path
        End If

        ShowSubFolders objSubfolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Awesome, so I've run this on my Windows system, but it returns the following error:

```
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
At F:\find.ps1:8 char:5
+ For  <<<< Each objFile in colFiles
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (OpenParenToken:Token
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword
```

I've played with it, guessing at how/where to add "(" but I don't really get anywhere.

Comment: What you've found is not a PowerShell snippet, but a piece of VBScript. Don't run VBScript in the PowerShell console

Answer (score 2):

This can be done much more concise in PowerShell, with the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet:

Recursively:

```
$Filter = {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)}
$OldStuff = Get-ChildItem "C:\your\base\dir" -File -Recurse | Where-Object $Filter
```

Or just the folder and its immediate subfolders (like in your example):

```
$Filter = {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)}
$OldStuff = Get-ChildItem "C:\your\base\dir" -File | Where-Object $Filter
$OldStuff += Get-ChildItem "C:\your\base\dir" -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem "C:\your\base\dir" -File | Where-Object $Filter 
}
```

---

### PowerShell 2.0

In version 2.0, the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet doesn't have the `-File` parameter. You can use `Where-Object` to test whether the item is a folder or not (using the `PsIsContainer` property):

Recursively:

```
$Filter = {-not($_.PsIsContainer) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90))}
$OldStuff = Get-ChildItem "C:\your\base\dir" -Recurse | Where-Object $Filter
```

Folder and its immediate subfolders:

```
$Filter = {-not($_.PsIsContainer) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90))}
$OldStuff = Get-ChildItem "C:\your\base\dir" | Where-Object $Filter
$OldStuff += Get-ChildItem "C:\your\base\dir" |Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer}| ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem "C:\your\base\dir" | Where-Object $Filter 
}
```

Comment: Mathias, thanks so much for your reply!  I tried both of your examples, and they both return an error:  

Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.
At F:\th.ps1:2 char:48
+ $OldStuff = Get-ChildItem "F:\CARGO_HOME" -File <<<<  | Where-Object $Filter
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand      

Did I do something wrong?  Thanks again for your help

Comment: @TonyH Please update your question with the error you receive when you use `Get-ChildItem` instead

Comment: @TonyH Ahh, you must be using PowerShell 2.0, I'll update the answer